# How can I turn a geometric shape into a hollow room with evenly thick walls?

Tags: mesh

so I as a Blender newbie is trying to model a hollow building. I was wondering if there's any easy way to turn this flat plain surface into an actual wall with thickness. The challenge is that it has window gaps, the wall is slanted outwards and that the walls are part of an octogon. How do I model an evenly thick wall from this here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *Solidify* modifier; To add it to a object, select said object, go to the *Properties*, and in the tab *Modifiers* click *Add Modifier* and select *Solidify*.

[image]

You can adjust the *Thickness* value.

Comment: Please don't use backticks for highlighting, this is reserved for code. Use *italics* or **bold** text.